# NPE при попытке получить подключение к БД из Data Source

Tags: java, postgresql, servlet, tomcat, connection

**Добрый день.**

При попытке получения коннекта из Connection Pool (находится в Data Source) получаю NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    mts.city.dao.PersonCheckDao.getConnection(PersonCheckDao.java:43)
    mts.city.dao.PersonCheckDao.checkPerson(PersonCheckDao.java:64)
    mts.city.web.CheckPersonServlet.doGet(CheckPersonServlet.java:54)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Если получать соединение не из пула коннектов, а через DriverManager.getConnection(...), то всё работает прекрасно.

Пытался загружать класс драйвера в разных местах(Хотя насколько понимаю это лишнее - tomcat сделает это сам посмотрев context.xml): в методе init, PoolConnectionBuilder, getConnection и перед его вызовом.

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

Пытался передать другой аргумент в ctx.lookup(), что вызывало NPE уже в этом месте (значит ресурс всё-таки находит корректно)

В чём может быть дело? Использую Tomcat9, база Postgresql.
Подозреваю, что мог где-то что-то не инициализировать, либо нужно было что-то ещё настроить со стороны Postgresql :(

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>City Register</display-name>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/cityRegister</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Resource
            auth="Container"
            driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
            maxActive="10"
            maxIdle="5"
            maxWait="50000"
            name="jdbc/cityRegister"
            username="postgres"
            password="root"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/city_register"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1">
    </Resource>
</Context>
```

PersonCheckDao

```
    public void setConnectionBuilder(ConnectionBuilder connectionBuilder) {
        logger.info("Задали билдер ");
        this.connectionBuilder = connectionBuilder;
        if (this.connectionBuilder == null) {
            logger.info("БИЛДЕР ПУСТОЙ");
        } else {
            logger.info("БИЛДЕР НЕ ПУСТОЙ");
        }
    }

    private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        logger.info("Попытка получить коннекшн ");
//      TODO : Тут оно и валится
        return connectionBuilder.getConnection();
    }
```

CheckPersonServlet

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
    logger.info("SERVLET IS CREATED..");
    dao = new PersonCheckDao();
    dao.setConnectionBuilder(new PoolConnectionBuilder());
}
```

PoolConnectionBuilder

```
public PoolConnectionBuilder() {
    try {
        Context ctx =  new InitialContext();
        dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/cityRegister");
        logger.info("Дата соурс загружен ");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        logger.error("ОШИБКА. Дата соурс не загружен", e);
    }
}

public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    logger.info("Попытка гет ");
    return this.dataSource.getConnection();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверил наличие соединений со стороны БД - при старте томкэта подлкючения к БД создавались корректно и ожидали использования.
Проверив весь стек, обнаружил, что в обработчике гет-запроса создаётся ещё один экземпляр dao, из которого я уже и пытаюсь получить соединение. Вероятно осталось после рефактора и перехода от прямого подключения к подключению через пул коннектов.